Kafka Consumer and Producer related question >> how to make it run parallely
How can I utilize Apache Kafka to handle data streams from multiple customers concurrently, ensuring that 10 records from each customer are consumed in parallel, with one Tomcat server acting as the producer and both Tomcat servers acting as consumers? Currently, I'm employing a Redis pub/sub system to distribute 10 records of each customer among two subscribers, but I aim to migrate this functionality to Kafka. Despite extensive research through various resources, including YouTube, ChatGPT, and forums like Phind, I haven't found a suitable solution.
chatGPT,phind i have tried

Kafka consumer defaults to poll up to 500 records per topic partition. How many partitions do you have? Processing in parallel isn't recommended if you care about offset commit ordering

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This design doesn't seem that scalable to me. Each customer you add will require another 10 threads. Are you sure you don't want a common pool of 10 parallel consumers for all customers?
Here's a few Kafka concepts to look for when looking through the docs / tutorials

Topics - Each topic is a separate log of events. I get the feeling you'll want one topic per customer

Partitioning - Topics are split into partitions. Kafka guarantees ordering within a single partition so reading/writing to a single partition is sequential. Ordering across partitions is not guaranteed so reading / writing can occur in parallel. If you want to read 10 records in parallel then I suggest choosing a partition count that is a multiple of 10. To future-proof yourself you might choose 100 partitions. Be sure to choose a partitioning strategy that is fair/evenly distributed and if you want to guarantee ordering of two or more messages, you need to ensure they are assigned the same partition (eg entry.getId().hashCode() % 100)

Consumer Groups - A group of consumers which share the same groupId. Kafka guarantees that each message will be delivered to only a single consumer in a consumer group. In your case you might want a consumer group per customer, and each consumer group has 10 members.



i  think you dint understand my question

perhaps ask your question in a better way then

Currently, I'm have a Redis pub/sub system ,in which i have 2 tomcats. where one tomcat will be the publisher and both will be the subscribers.
my Use case :- i have 3 customers. i get data from all customers and it will be added to mysql database. publisher picks 10 records of each customer and gives to the subscribers and this cycle repeats.
how do i migrate this to kafka? with same 2 tomcat configuration.Please help
i have tried using chatgpt phind but didnot fine any solution
